# In NetBeans, Ivy dependencies used at compile time, but not runtime

Tags: netbeans, ivy

I am new to NetBeans (version 7.2), and am trying to configure it for use with a project whose dependencies are configured with Apache Ivy.  I have installed the Ivy plugin, modified my ivy.xml file to match the expected configurations ([compile, runtime, compile-test, runtime-test].  The project builds cleanly, and the appropriate libraries are present in the "Ivy Libraries/Runtime" project tree.  However when I try to run the application in NetBeans, I get NoClassDefFoundError on classes that were imported by Ivy.

I assume that, somehow, I need to explicitly tell NetBeans to use the Ivy Libraries at runtime.  But I can't figure out how to do it.  Please stackoverflow, you're my only hope.

Answer (score 0):

The primary problem is that I was just hitting the "run" button on the project.  I'm not sure what class it was trying to run.  But when I selected the actual class containing my main() method, and explicitly ran that one, it worked (or rather, it failed in a sensible way).